# Why can't you run a task and catch it in another method

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-core, task, razor-pages

Why isn't it possible to start a task and await it in another method?
Or is there a way to catch the result of the task.
So you know it is completed?

like for example (based on razor PageModel):

```
public Task OnGet()
{
    var runningTask = StartLongProccessingTask(); //returns Task that creates a file
}

//this gets fired from a button with `asp-page-handler="DownloadFile"`
public Task OnPostDownloadFile()
{
    await runningTask;
    return File(".\Example.docx");
}
```

I've tried to store the task in a global variable but to no result.

Comment: Because your `runningTask` variable is local to `OnGet`. (Also, your `OnPostDownloadFile` lacks the `async` modifier.) You can certainly wait for a task in another method...otherwise, how would any of `async/await` even work? A `Task` is a wrapper for a result that you will have _at some point in time_.

Comment: Instead of having a local variable `var runningTask` make it a class variable (outside of your method): `private Task _runningTask;`. Now you can await this task wherever you want. But you have to think about a `null` check.

Comment: Also, it helps to use the proper terminology. A task isn't "caught". Exceptions are caught. Tasks are "awaited".

Comment: A task can be awaited on another method but not another *request*. A new controller instance is created for each HTTP request. If you want to start a long-running task in the background you should check [Background Task with hosted services in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Answer (score 0):

You have some misconcepts here:

1. First of all, runningTask is a variable inside method `OnGet()`, this means it is in another context, and your Method `OnPostDownloadFile()` doesnt know that variable.
2. Secondly, you cant use the await keyword inside a synchronous task, that task would need to be Async in order for you to be able to use the await keyword, and what you should be awaiting is the return of the method `OnGet()`

Provided what I wrote above,

What you should do, is make you `OnPostDownload()` Method an async task and await the return of the `OnGet()` task. Therefore you also need to return something from the `OnGet()` task